# How to override/remove the transition when going back in React Navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm creating a custom modal and would like to remove the back transition animation in React Navigation.

I have tried what is below, it removes the animation when I navigate to the modal component, but does not remove it when going back from the modal to the previous component.

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
    { ... },
    {
        transitionConfig: () => ({
            transitionSpec: {
                duration: 0,
            },
        }),
    }
);
```

So when I go back, there's a slideDown animation and I expect there to be none. I have only tested it on Android. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: refer link https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1254#issuecomment-297457689

Comment: Do you mean to remove the access to go back to the previous stack/screen?

Comment: @hongdevelop I tried it, but I have the same problem

Comment: @CarlosAbraham no, I still want to be able to go back, but I want to remove the slideDown transition

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: No... but right now I'm testing this library (http://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/) and it seems possible, well at least the animations are smooth compared to react-navigation